# Winter Bash 2017: Hats are coming again soon!

Tags: discussion, hats

### It's almost time for Winter Bash 2017!

For several years now, Stack Exchange has run a holiday event called [**Winter Bash**](http://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)! It's a fun little event where users collect "hats" that you can wear on your avatars by doing various things (post on a certain day, get a question to a certain score, and things like that).

This year the event will start on December 13, 2017, and it'll run up to and including January 3, 2018. After that, the hats we've earned will all disappear.

Long story short . . .

### [Hats are coming again soon! :-)](http://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/)

*(**Note**: Users who don't want to see hats will be able to click a button labeled "I hate hats".)*

Comment: What do you mean "hats that you can wear on your avatars" ?  Do I have avatars in this site? Where? Just passing by....   :D

Comment: @McMillanCheng When I say "avatar", I'm referring to the square image that appears on your profile and on your posts.  They're called by various names on different websites, including "profile picture" or "icon".  Mine is a picture of a snail, so as soon as Winter Bash starts, I can put hats on that snail :-)

Comment: Wow! Sounds great! I am looking forward..    :D.. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Why not transform earned hats into rep point when it's their time to disappear?

Comment: @SovereignSun - No, no, no. Just enjoy the hats.

Comment: @Sovereign this is just supposed to be a fun, little bit silly game. Rep is sometimes a holy war O.o

Comment: @M.A.R. Everything in life should have a good reason to exist, fun is nothing really, it's rubbish. These hats really don't make sense if they are only for fun. I, personally, can't see anything funny about them.

Comment: @SovereignSun [8 Health Benefits of Having Fun](https://heelthatpain.com/8-health-benefits-of-having-fun/) You may not find the hats fun, that's OK, but don't go saying that there's no point to fun, because that's just simply not true. There are numerous scientific studies on fun and its benefits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This is this*
*And that is that*
*Now I can't wait*
*To wear a hat!*

(Some news is so good it just provokes spontaneous rhyme.)

Comment: This or that, that and this, when you wear a hat, you just can't miss.

Comment: @ColleenV - The hats are here! I think that's great. No longer do we need to wait.

Answer (score 3):

Winter bash hats rock.
So don't you click "I hate hats."
You know you like them.

<sup>Haiku courtesy of my husband</sup>

I'm looking at you Arau-"bah humbug"-caria ... 8)

Comment: Have an upvote from me 8). (humbug!)

Answer (score 1):

Booh! I hate hats. Especially during the festive season.